# How did the Bozeman come 90 years into the future in "Cause and Effect"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

How is that, during the events of "[Cause and Effect](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode))" the *Enterprise-D* got trapped in the [temporal causality loop](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Temporal_causality_loop) for only 17.4 days when the USS Bozeman was in that loop for 90 years?

What was keeping the Bozeman inside the loop before the Enterprise-D showed up?

[image]

Comment: Kelsey Grammar is used to playing the same role for decades at a time.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty convincing. Is there any further info you'd like to see before you accept one of the answers given?

Answer (score 21):

The [Bozeman](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Bozeman) was only in the **loop** for the same amount of time as the Enterprise: 17.4 days.

- The Bozeman approaches the rift in 2278.
- The Enterprise approaches the rift in 2368.
- The Bozeman travels through the rift and emerges in 2368.
- The two ships collide and the resulting explosion causes the rift to rupture, resetting the timeline **(on both sides of the rift)** by 4.3 days.
- The "loop" happens four times. We see each loop.

---

The resulting explosion (caused by the two ships colliding) seems to extend to a distance of approximate 3-4 light years in every direction on **both sides of the rift**. Ironically, this sort of paradox, where a temporal effect *precedes* a first-cause is almost exactly mirrored in the [final episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Good_Things) of TNG.

Per the [episode script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/218.txt):

> **Geordi:** *Worf refers to a "distortion." If this were a temporal distortion, and if we were close enough to it... it's possible that a
>   large enough explosion might've ruptured the space-time continuum.*
>
> *We collided... exploded... and got stuck in this repeating loop of time.*

Comment: -That both ships were caught in the loop for only 17 days makes good sense and is canonically valid. The Bozeman slips the timeline and collides with Enterprise and the resulting explosion at the end of the Bozeman time-slip causes the loop. That loop actually saves the lives of both crews because it buys the Enterprise crew enough time to figure out what happened and to 'fix' it.

Comment: Yes,  the Bozeman's 'time slip' and the Enterprise and Bozeman's 'time loop' are different phenomena, albeit caused by the same anomaly.

Comment: That could make sense if you take Geordi's "temporal distortion" as a separate phenomenon from the "rupture" in space-time caused by the explosion, and only the latter caused the loop...in that case, if the Enterprise hadn't been there the Bozeman might have just been thrown forward in time by the temporal distortion but not caught in a time loop. Not sure if the writers had this specific idea in mind but it's a logical in-universe explanation.

Comment: @Hypnosifl -An entire Galaxy and 90 years of separation and the Bozeman STILL runs into the Enterprise.

Comment: @Morgan - They were both investigating the same anomaly, following standard Starfleet procedures that (presumably) haven't changed in 90 years.

Comment: @Morgan - it does seem like a strange coincidence, but you could imagine that part of how this distortion works is that massive objects that enter at different times are attracted to one another in some way, pulling the one that entered earlier into the same region of time as the one that entered later. If it hadn't been for the Enterprise entering in 2368, the Bozeman might not have been yanked forward at all, or at least not as much.

Comment: @Hypnosifl -Richard makes a good observation too about the two ships investigating the same 'anomaly' in different time periods. Mayhap as you say the Bozeman was drawn to the Enterprise as it approached 'the other end. I'm not well versed on temporal mechanics so leave that to others. My comments and answer was pointed at the question posed as in relation to how and why they broke the loop rather than spend eternity in a perpetual 'Groundhog Day'.

Comment: @Morgan - There's no canon explanation of why the anomaly carried them forwards 90 years. Out of universe, it was simply because the writer wanted to include a Constitution class ship (he's a big fan of TOS). Ironically, due to finances they ended up not doing it; http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)#Background_information

Comment: @Richard -There are wormholes that are a conduit between different locations, why not 'wormholes' that are a conduit between different times? As Q warned, "It's wondrous, with treasures to satiate desires, both subtle and gross." Is this one such wonder?

Comment: Upvoted your answer: firmer, more succinct, and clearer than mine.  Plus, I do like minutiae's script better, notwithstanding the arguably unfair (albeit unchallenged) use of the copyrighted screenplay.

Comment: @Rob - Paramount have traditionally ignored the use of copyrighted Trek material where used for non-commercial purposes. It may interest you that there's an entire fan-made TV series comprised of the unused "[Phase II](http://www.startreknewvoyages.com/)" scripts.

Answer (score 3):

The episode is not entirely clear about whether the Bozeman was caught in the same causality loop for 90 years as opposed to 17 days, or whether it happened into a time warp that landed it in the Enterprise's path 90 years later.  In the episode, the Bozeman's captain, Bateson, says that their "sensors detected a temporal distortion. Then your ship [the Enterprise] appeared."  While Picard then speculates that the Bozeman may also have been in a temporal causality loop like the Enterprise, this is not explicitly established.  (See the script at http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/218.htm, an unofficial script-transcribing site.  I don't have access to an official screenplay.)

Rather than assuming that the Bozeman was in a 90-year causality loop, one could just as easily interpret Bateson's statement as evidence that the Bozeman entered into a temporal anomaly and emerged 90 years later in the Enterprise's path, and *then* spent 17 days in the same causality loop as the Enterprise.  Given the equivocal manner in which Bateson explained the Bozeman's presence in Picard's era, and the presence in canon of time-traveling Federation vessels (see, for example, the Enterprise C of Yesterday's Enterprise), this seems to me an equally plausible explanation. This also makes more sense because each iteration of the Enterprise's causality loop was dependent upon the Bozeman's presence and interaction with the Enterprise; the Enterprise was only available to the Bozeman to collide with for 17 days, which means that the Bozeman was in the same causality loop, for 17 days.

Comment: Chakoteya is fine, but st-minutiae.com has a full set of TNG scripts; http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/218.txt

Comment: @Richard: Does that site have permission from the copyright holders to publish those scripts? The front page says "This website is intended for personal use only, under “fair use” principles of United States copyright law.", but I hardly think "fair use" applies to entire scripts.

Comment: @KeithThompson - The short answer is no, the long answer is that scripts and trek related properties are considered "fair use" by Paramount as long as there's no attempt to monetise them.

Comment: @Richard: Can you cite a published statement from Paramount to that effect? (I wasn't aware of that, and I flagged your original comment.)

Comment: @KeithThompson - Trek Minutiae has been around since 2000 and has openly hosted scripts for nearly 10 years. There's a nice quite from the President of Paramount stating that they only want to target sites "who are either selling ads or collecting fees, selling illegal merchandise, or posting copyrighted materials [e.g. episodes and films] on their sites to refrain from these specific activities"... http://www.oocities.org/wellesley/garden/6220/trek.html

Comment: From the linked article: "Paramount has not asked any site to 'shut down'",he wrote. "It has asked Star Trek webmasters who are either selling ads, collecting fees, selling illegal merchandise, or **posting copyrighted materials on their sites** to refrain from these specific activities." (emphasis added) That doesn't sound to me like permission to post entire scripts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14575/discussion-between-richard-and-keith-thompson)

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to the personnel on board the Enterprise and their unique combination of abilities. La Forge and his visor, Crusher and her curiosity, Data and his positronic brain, Troi and her empathic ability all combined their clues and with 90 years advancement in diagnostic ability over the Bozeman helped them to solve the puzzle.

> In the end it came down to Data sending the clue to himself in the next loop (the number 3, the number of Riker's rank pips) in order to end the cycle and break the loop. The Bozeman had no such combination of abilities and no Data on board. He was the real key to escaping the loop.

The Bozeman was trapped because they never realized they were in a loop or didn't figure it out in time before getting recycled and forgot all they learned. Even if they came to realize what happened in one loop they wouldn't be able to communicate with the next loop to change a critical choice to break it. The difference was the personnel aboard the different ships. Setting aside the 90 years advanced technology advantage and consider the players. Enterprise has a 1/2 Betazoid, an Engineer with a high-tech prosthetic and an android with a positronic brain collaborating to communicate with next loop.

> If not for Data's ability, the Enterprise could have been forever trapped with the Bozeman in that loop.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question--it's not "why weren't the Bozeman crew smart enough to find a way out of the loop" but "why was the Bozeman in a loop at all, if it wasn't crashing into the Enterprise and creating an explosion in every cycle". Geordi said specifically that the explosion had somehow created the loop: "If this were a temporal distortion, and if we were close enough to it, it's possible that a large enough explosion might've ruptured the space-time continuum. We collided, exploded, then got stuck in this repeating loop of time."

Comment: @Hypnosifl -They were trapped because they didn't realize it or didn't figure it out in time before getting recycled and forgot all they learned. Even if they came to realize what happened in one loop they wouldn't be able to communicate with the next loop to change a critical choice to break it. The difference was the personnel aboard the different ships. Setting aside the 90 years advanced technology advantage and consider the players. Enterprise has a 1/2 Betazoid, an Engineer with a high-tech prosthetic and an android with a positronic brain collaborating to communicate with next loop.

Comment: The Bozeman didn't have these advantages. As the Enterprise crew showed, they too would have been caught in the loop along with the Bozeman if not for Data's ingenuity and ability.

Comment: I think you're still not understanding the point--according to Geordi's explanation, there shouldn't even *be* a time loop if there wasn't a massive explosion. So how could the Bozeman have entered a time loop 90 years earlier if there was no Enterprise to crash into it?

Comment: "How is that the Enterprise got trapped in the temporal causality loop for only 17 days when the Bozeman was in that loop for 90 years?" I explained why they got out. "What was keeping the Bozeman in that loop before the Enterprise showed up?" They kept making the same choices based on the same circumstances time after time so didn't break the cycle/loop. He didn't ask what 'caused' the temporal loop in the first place, he asked why the Enterprise got out after 17 days and why the Bozeman was still trapped after 90 years.

Comment: @Morgan: I too think you are misunderstanding the question. The Bozeman crew did *not* keep making the same choices for 90 years, because *there was no loop* before the Enterprise showed up. The explosion of the Enterprise was what *started* the loop (or rather, each explosion of the Enterprise started another iteration of the loop), so there is no point in claiming the Bozeman was trapped *in the loop* for 90 years. The loop could not have started before the Enterprise showed up, hence the question being asked is what kept the Bozeman there for 90 years until the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper -I never said the Bozeman was in the loop for 90 years, Peter Nosko did in his OP. I said the Enterprise had a 90 year technological/diagnostic advantage over the Bozeman. It was a 90 year old ship as compared to the Enterprise, was it not? Please re-read the OP and then my answer. His question was actually two questions in one. My answer focused on and answered the first question and Richard answered the second by pointing out that the Bozeman also was only in the loop for 17.4 years after their time-slip.

Comment: @Morgan: Ok, maybe I misinterpreted you there partially. Statements of yours such as "he asked why the Enterprise got out after 17 days and why the Bozeman was still trapped after 90 years." sounded to me as if you imply the Bozeman crew had 90 years to figure out what was going on, which does not seem to be the case. Indeed, it's probably true that both the Enterprise and the Bozeman had some 17 days (with the additional difficulty of a time-loop/memory-reset penalty) and the Enterprise crew solved the problem based upon its unique advantages in crew and systems, but then, the OP ...

Comment: ... explicitly contrasted the Enterprise's 17 days with the Bozeman's 90 years as the basis for their questions. As that contrast is based on the misunderstanding that the Bozeman was in the time loop for 90 years, explaining why the Enterprise and not the Bozeman solved the puzzle within 17 days is somewhat beside the point.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper -It seems that Richard and Peter cleaned up that misconception about the storyline timeline  implication rather well.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I was under the impression that the Bozeman was caught in the loop for 90 years, but I think I like the explanation already said here that they came through the temporal rift - going 90 years forward in time as a result - and *then* got caught in the loop by colliding with the Enterprise. Assuming this is the case, I still have one question, though. Once the loop is broken, why doesn't the Bozeman just turn around and fly back through the rift to get back to its own time?

Comment: You've provided some good information, but if you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Feel free to include a link to this question and your details in your question.

Comment: This just agrees with what another answer says, then asks a different question.