# Which starship has travelled back in time the most number of times?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, spaceship

The title says it all: **Which starship has travelled back in time the most number of times?**  The only restriction is it must be from canon.  It can be from any society (not just Starfleet or Federation), any time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Enterprise-D** seems to be the winner here.

In the episode [TNG: Cause and Effect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)) the Bozeman and the Enterprise both travel back in time four times.

The Enterprise also travels backwards on several occasions (at least twice, possibly many more) in "[TNG: We'll Always Have Paris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/We%27ll_Always_Have_Paris_(episode))" due to the [Manhein Effect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Manheim_Effect) and twice in [TNG: Timescape](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timescape_(episode)).

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment on another answer to another question, "Cause and Effect" implies more time loops than we see, making the *Enterprise-D*'s win even greater.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - I disagree. Based on the script, there's every indication that we saw all four loops.

Comment: So, what you're saying, basically, is "THERE ARE FOUR LOOPS!" But seriously, do you really think they memorized the poker game that quickly?

Comment: The Enterprise D is stuck in the rift for 17.4 days (this is stated in the episode).  While it's hard to know how long each loop is, if we assume 2 or 3 days each loop, then we're talking 6 to 9 loops in total.  We only _saw_ four of them.  Remember, the episode _begins_ with the _end_ of a loop.

Comment: @Tim - There are 4.3 days between each loop. A very simply calculation reveals that that works out to almost precisely 4, which fits in very nicely with what we see in the episode. First loop happens off-screen. Second loop is barely noticed, third loop is noticed and a message sent into the fourth which allows the release.

Comment: Where do you get the 4.3 days from?

Comment: @Tim - Although Geordi postulates that the ship may have been through multiple loops, the script is rather more circumspect. We see the end of the first loop. The second loop manifests as deja vu, the third loop results in genuine knowledge as does the fourth loop. There's no good indication that they've been through more than four loops other than Geordi saying it.

Comment: @Tim - That being said, feel free to ask this as a main site question.

Answer (score 2):

## The original USS Enterprise...

According to [this list of time travel episodes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_travel_episodes), the original Enterprise travels back in time 4 times:

- Once in 'The Naked Time' (to three days earlier)
- Twice in 'Tomorrow is Yesterday'
- Once in 'Assignment Earth'

## ...and the USS Bozeman

which travelled back in time 4 times during the course of *TNG* 'Cause and Effect (kudos @Richard)

Comment: The Enterprise and the Bozeman both travel in time four times; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56436/how-did-the-bozeman-come-90-years-into-the-future-in-cause-and-effect?lq=1

Comment: @Richard Ah, yes of course - I must be tired!

Comment: If "sent" means under official auspices only Assignment: Earth would qualify.