# Which starship gets destroyed the most often?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

The question "[Which starship has been sent back in time the most number of times?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126509/which-starship-has-been-sent-back-in-time-the-most-number-of-times)" made me wonder...

**Which starship has been *destroyed* on screen the most?**

Time travel loops count individually, but watching a recording of the same in-universe destruction only count once. For instance, only the actual self-destruct in "The Search for Spock" counts, not any replays in later films.

Comment: [Highly relevant](http://chainsawsuit.com/comic/2013/02/04/the-star-trek-movie-idea-vault/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Enterprise-D was destroyed **eleven** times.

- [TNG2x13: Time Squared](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Squared_(episode)) - Once.
- [TNG5x18: Cause and Effect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)) - Four times.
- [TNG6x25: Timescape](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timescape_(episode)) - Once
- [TNG7x11: Parallels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallels_(episode)) - Once
- [TNG7x26: All Good Things](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)) - Three times.
- [Generations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations) - Once

Close-but-no-cigar for [TNG3x15: Yesterday's Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yesterday%27s_Enterprise_(episode)), where it was almost certainly destroyed, but not actually seen on screen because the timeline reverted.

Comment: In "Cause and Effect", the destruction rate of the *Enterprise-D* was implied to be much higher than what we saw on screen. The loop appeared to be less than a day long, yet when the ship finally broke the chain of events that cause the loop, the ship's clock was over 17 days off.

Comment: @JohnSensebe Yup, but it was only **seen** four times.

Comment: An *Enterprise-D* was also destroyed in "Parallels" (TNG7x11).

Comment: @JohnSensebe Thanks! I had a feeling I was missing a Worf-centric episode, but I couldn't figure out which one it was.

Comment: Riker seems to be involved in a lot of these, too. In "Parallels", Crazy Beard Riker gets his *Enterprise* destroyed, in "All Good Things", Future Riker gets his ship destroyed, and in *Generations*, he's put in command for a few minutes, and guess what? He was also in command in "Timescape", and he was going to ram the Borg ship in "Best of Both Worlds, Part One", as well. I guess giving the correct advice in "Cause and Effect" makes up for it...