# How many times has the Enterprise been destroyed?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

How many times has the starship *Enterprise* been destroyed?  This includes the NX-01 as well as any of the others we have seen, starting with the NCC-1701, without any letters suffixed on the end or with any letters suffixed to it.  (In other words, yes, NCC-1701-A, B, C....)

Along with that, how many times were off screen and how many were on screen?  (And, yes, counted individually per each ship named *Enterprise*!)

For example, we know the Enterprise-C was destroyed in *Yesterday's Enterprise* when it gets sent back in time, but we don't see it, so that's off screen.  [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126532/1693) provides a good start in answering this question, since it gives counts for the NCC-1701-D, however, we know that in *Cause and Effect*, the Enterprise was destroyed more than the number of times we witnessed it exploding, since the time loop was repeated a number of times.

This would include all the TV shows, TOS movies, TNG movies, and reboot movies.

Comment: Retcon: Zero times. With Greedo at the helm, no Enterprises were harmed in the making of any of the films or the series episodes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am basing the following list on Star Trek canon only.

## Destructions seen on-screen

**NCC-1701**

- Destroyed on-screen in *STIII* by Kirk himself (footage repeated at special hearing of Federation Council in *STIV*, but this was the same incident, so will not count separately)

**NCC-1701-D**

- Destroyed on-screen 4 times in "Cause and Effect", but another was heard in the conference room on a distorted audio recording (which was not necessarily one of the previously-seen ones), so will say 5 times on screen

[image]

- Once in each of "Time Squared, "Timescape", and "Parallels"
- "All Good Things" provides 3 more destructions
- Destroyed (for good) in *Generations*

**NX-01**

- The Imperial Warship Enterprise was destroyed by the Tholians in "Through a Mirror Darkly"

**NCC-1701 (reboot)**

- Destroyed in *Star Trek Beyond*

**Total destructions on-screen: 15**

## Destructions alluded to off-screen

**NCC-1701-C**

- Implied to be destroyed after being sent back through temporal rift in *TNG* "Yesterday's Enterprise" (although this is retconned in "Redemption", when we discover that the crew had actually been captured by the Romulans, and so ship presumably survived and was studied by them)

**NCC-1701-D**

- Additional 12 destructions in "Cause and Effect" based on

> **WORF:** Time base confirms our chronometers are off by seventeen point four days,

and assuming one destruction per day (and subtracting the 5 on-screen destructions we counted previously)

- One additional implied destruction in "Yesterday's Enterprise", while protecting the Enterprise-C

**NX-01**

- In *Enterprise* "E²", a copy of the NX-01 created by a Xindi subspace corridor is implied to have been destroyed by the end of the episode

**Total destructions off-screen: 15**

## Total number of destructions: 30

## Enterprises with final fates unknown / not enough info to conclude destruction

- NX-01
- NCC-1701-A (decommissioned in *STVI*)
- NCC-1701-B
- NCC-1701-E
- NCC-1701-A (reboot)

Comment: Minor quibble - the capture of the Enterprise-C crew was revealed in "Redemption", not "Yesterday's Enterprise".  It is assumed to have happened immediately after (from the Ent-C's perspective) the events of that episode, but Sela explains how she came to exist in "Redemption".

Comment: Also - this question / answer leaves the Enterprise-D with 11 destructions - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126531/which-starship-gets-destroyed-the-most-often/126532#126532

Comment: @NKCampbell: Note that the answer you link to (which I reference in the question) only counts the ONSCREEN destructions.  This answer includes what I think is a pretty fair estimate of how many times it went through the loop and was destroyed off screen.

Comment: seventeen point four days + assuming one destruction per day = 17 destructions

Comment: @Axelrod : No --- I already counted 5 of those as on-screen destructions previously.  The difference is 17-5=12 off-screen destructions.

Comment: @Valorum : Yes.  That was already in my answer.

Comment: Re: Enterprise-C: That the crew was captured is not strong evidence that the ship survived. They may have escaped the ship's destruction via escape pods or shuttles, or been beamed off by the Romulans in between The Enterprise's loss of shields and destruction.

Comment: @Politank-Z : It's only a speculation and doesn't change the count either way.

Comment: Does the NX-01 entry really count as destroyed if it never existed?

Comment: You forgot about the Imperial Navy Starship Enterprise in "*Through a Mirror Darkly*". It was destroyed by the Thollians. Your account should be 30 trashed Enterprises.

Comment: @DonaldBrown : Added.  Thanks!

Comment: What about the parallel Enterprises in "Parallels" ?   Like the one with *Castaway* Riker?

Answer (score -8):

The correct answer is six times, the Enterprise -the most powerful ship in starfleet- has been destroyed six times, which begs the question, why name a ship after a cursed name?

Comment: From the above answer you can see this is wrong, what makes you think it's 6?

Comment: Did you read the selected answer before providing your own?  It's a well supported answer and you don't even provide a list of the six times you feel are correct.  (And note the supported answer is a lot more than six.)